# Arduino IR sensor - low range

Tags: c, arduino, hardware

I'm programming Arduino. I have a problem with the IR sensor. It only detects this ball (equiped with IR LEDS) in range of 0,5m and I would need at least 2m. This is the ball:
"http://drgraeme.net/drgraeme-free-nxt-g-tutorials/Ch108/SoccerGenIINXTG/Soccer%20Ball/HiTechnicRCJ05V2.jpg"
and this is my arduino code:

```
// digital pin 2 has a pushbutton attached to it. Give it a name:
int IR = 2;
int i = 0;
int ii = 0;
int led = 0;


void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(IR, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() { 
  i = 0;
  ii = 0;
  do
  {
  i = i + 1;
  int STANJE1 = digitalRead(IR);
   if(STANJE1 < 1)
   {
   ii = ii + 1; 
   } 
  }while(i<1000);

if(ii > 1)
{Serial.println("IS");}
else{Serial.println("IS NOT");}  
}
```

IR sensor is 38kHZ and the balls LEDs are 40kHZ, but I found a program that allowed me to detect the ball 10m away from sensor, but It was ment for something else, and I didn't understand it, so that is not the problem.
This is the code that works further (That's because it doesn't use "DigitalRead()")

```
/* Raw IR decoder sketch!

 This sketch/program uses the Arduno and a PNA4602 to 
 decode IR received. This can be used to make a IR receiver
 (by looking for a particular code)
 or transmitter (by pulsing an IR LED at ~38KHz for the
 durations detected 

 Code is public domain, check out www.ladyada.net and adafruit.com
 for more tutorials! 
 */

// We need to use the 'raw' pin reading methods
// because timing is very important here and the digitalRead()
// procedure is slower!
//uint8_t IRpin = 2;
// Digital pin #2 is the same as Pin D2 see
// http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168 for the 'raw' pin mapping
#define IRpin_PIN      PIND
#define IRpin          2

// the maximum pulse we'll listen for - 65 milliseconds is a long time
#define MAXPULSE 65000

// what our timing resolution should be, larger is better
// as its more 'precise' - but too large and you wont get
// accurate timing
#define RESOLUTION 20 

// we will store up to 100 pulse pairs (this is -a lot-)
uint16_t pulses[100][2];  // pair is high and low pulse 
uint8_t currentpulse = 0; // index for pulses we're storing

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Ready to decode IR!");
}

void loop(void) {
  uint16_t highpulse, lowpulse;  // temporary storage timing
  highpulse = lowpulse = 0; // start out with no pulse length


//  while (digitalRead(IRpin)) { // this is too slow!
    while (IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)) {
     // pin is still HIGH

     // count off another few microseconds
     highpulse++;
     delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);

     // If the pulse is too long, we 'timed out' - either nothing
     // was received or the code is finished, so print what
     // we've grabbed so far, and then reset
     if ((highpulse >= MAXPULSE) && (currentpulse != 0)) {
       printpulses();
       currentpulse=0;
       return;
     }
  }
  // we didn't time out so lets stash the reading
  pulses[currentpulse][0] = highpulse;

  // same as above
  while (! (IRpin_PIN & _BV(IRpin))) {
     // pin is still LOW
     lowpulse++;
     delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);
     if ((lowpulse >= MAXPULSE)  && (currentpulse != 0)) {
       printpulses();
       currentpulse=0;
       return;
     }
  }
  pulses[currentpulse][1] = lowpulse;

  // we read one high-low pulse successfully, continue!
  currentpulse++;
}

void printpulses(void) {
  Serial.println("\n\r\n\rReceived: \n\rOFF \tON");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < currentpulse; i++) {
    Serial.print(pulses[i][0] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
    Serial.print(" usec, ");
    Serial.print(pulses[i][1] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
    Serial.println(" usec");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post also the other program?

Comment: yes, I'll edit my original post

Comment: try the second code using while (digitalRead(IRpin)) { instead of while (IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)) { and tell me if there is difference

Comment: yes, digitalRead(IRpin) is taking longer

Comment: alsp attachInterrupt is a nice solution

Comment: I don't know man, I'm out of ideas. I tried to make my own "digitalRead()" method and I did it, but It was still reading it only 0.5m away max.

Comment: when the second program run slower, it works at 10m or less??

Comment: the second program doesn't have the same function. The second program doesn't give me values 0 or 1 constantly, but only once